# How to minimize function repetition using element data-attribute?

Tags: javascript

My jQuery code is working but I want to minimal it by data attribute. Please see below my HTML and jQuery code.

The functions below are repeated upto four times and I want to minimize/reduce this repetition. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.nav-menu-list ul li:nth-child(1)').hover(function() {
  $('#item-01').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $('#item-01').fadeOut();
});
$('.nav-menu-list ul li:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
  $('#item-02').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $('#item-02').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="nav-menu-list">
  <ul>
    <li data-id="item-01"><h2>home</h2></li>
    <li data-id="item-02"><h2>about us</h2></li>
    <li data-id="item-03"><h2>category</h2></li>
    <li data-id="item-04"><h2>news room</h2></li>
    <li data-id="item-05"><h2>blog</h2></li>
    <li data-id="item-06"><h2>contact us</h2></li>
  </ul>
</span>

<span class="nav-menu-list-details">
  <div id="item-01"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="item-02"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="item-03"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="item-04"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="item-05"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="item-06"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" /></div>
</span>
```

Comment: You could instead give class names to the `<li>`s and use CSS to activate a hover state with animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only a single function to control all of them.

But, for this, in the jQuery selector you must use `$('.nav-menu-list ul li')`.
With this selector, `hover()` context will be the `li` itself, then, just get the `data-id` of the current hovered `li` and then use it to select the div you want to target.

See below, I suggest to use full page ("Expand Snippet") mode on the snippet to better visualization:

```js
$('.nav-menu-list ul li').hover(function() {
  let id = "#" + $(this).data("id")
  $(id).fadeIn();
}, function() {
  let id = "#" + $(this).data("id")
  $(id).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.nav-menu-list-details div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="nav-menu-list">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="item-01"><h2>home</h2></li>
        <li data-id="item-02"><h2>about us</h2></li>
        <li data-id="item-03"><h2>category</h2></li>
        <li data-id="item-04"><h2>news room</h2></li>
        <li data-id="item-05"><h2>blog</h2></li>
        <li data-id="item-06"><h2>contact us</h2></li>
    </ul>
</span>

<span class="nav-menu-list-details">
    <div id="item-01"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_1</div>
    <div id="item-02"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_2</div>
    <div id="item-03"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_3</div>
    <div id="item-04"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_4</div>
    <div id="item-05"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_5</div>
    <div id="item-06"><img src="images/home-preview.png" alt="" />ITEM_6</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your suggestion and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider that the event target is the single object, even if the target includes a multitude of items:

```
$('.nav-menu-list ul li').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).data().id; 
    $("#"+id).fadeIn();
}, function(){
    var id = $(this).data().id; 
    $('#'+id).fadeOut();
});
```